# Share deadline_timer between two threads

Tags: c++, boost, timer, boost-thread

I need to share a boost::deadline_timer between two threads. The boost documentation says "The shared instances are not threadsafe". Here is an example code:

```
ClassA : public enable_shared_from_this<ClassA>{

  ClassA()
  {
    m_timer = new boost::deadline_timer(m_io_service);
  }

  destroy()
  {
    m_timer->cancel();
    delete m_timer;
    m_timer = NULL;
  }

  thread_method()
  {
    m_timer->expire_from_now(...);
    m_timer->async_wait(...);
  }

   run()
   {
     boost::thread t(ClassA::thread_method, shared_from_this);
   }
}
```

My question is "To synchronize timer access between destroy() and thread_method(), can I use boost::atomic ?

**Header:**

```
boost::atomic<boost::deadline_timer*> m_timer;
```

**Constructor:**

```
m_timer = new boost::deadline_timer(m_io_service);
```

Is it thread-safe ?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried compiling your own code to see if you have any issues?

Comment: @inetknght why do you need to know? He's not really asking for help with compiler errors or some such. I think there's enough information there (if not _too much_).

Comment: The code compiles but sometimes I have crash because the thread tries to access to m_timer while the other thread has deleted m_timer. So I think I need to use mutex in destroy() and thread_method(), no ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No that won't help.

The atomic only makes stores/loads *of the pointer* indivisible. When you dereference it, you're just accessing the `deadline_timer` directly, unsynchronized.

So you can either

- just traditional thread synchronization around all accesses to the deadline timer (e.g. using a `mutex`)
- use an Asio `strand` to create a 'logical' thread of execution, and take care to only access the dead line timer from that strand.

The strand approach is potentially more efficient but requires you to think about the flow of execution more accurately so you don't accidentally create a data race

Comment: I will use mutex, it is easier. Thanks.